# Which are the right permissions for a website

Tags: permissions

I'm working on a php website based on a mysql database (that's a first for me!) and I'm having trouble understand which permissions assign to the different files and folders.

I want people to be able to see the .php files in the main directory but not to have access to the files in the views, pictures and includes directories (that are used by the .php files in the main directory). 
Is it possible for example that an image can be loaded by the index.php file but not be seen by an user that types

www.website.it/images/exampleimage.jpg

This is a web site for anonymous users, there is no log in.
Who are owner, group and others in this case? The anonymous user is others?

Sorry if my question may seem silly but I'm new to this world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can store files outside the *served* directory. Those files might then be reached by php to build a page but not by the http server that will only serve from the specified directory.